# AnkhSVN & Web Site

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I have a solution that have 3 project. These project is not in the same folder, so AnkhSVN cannot open these project and displays *projectname(unavailable)*.

[image: Solution Explorer with missing projects]

So how to fix this problem?

I have downloaded the latest version of AnkhSVN today but the problem persists.

Comment: what's the link between ankhsvn and the opening of projects ?

Comment: Its not Ankhsvn fault. Try remove projects from solution and add them again.I think you moved projects, but solution still pointing to previous projects directory.

Comment: i use collabnet subversion edge . this problem is not for local , it for when we use server.

Comment: [link](http://img.majidonline.com/pic/276490/Untitled.png) this is a screenshot of solution explorer

Comment: AnkhSVN upto 2.3 doesn't support automatic checkouts of secondary working copies (like any other Subversion client). In 2.4 the information stored in the .sln file is extended to allow this scenario to start working. In the initial 2.4 release the checkout is not automatic yet, but you can perform the checkout in the context menu on the failed project.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the the solution, and then deleting the **projectname.suo** file in the solution directory.